# Embedding Python interpreter in C leads to segfault when loading with ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I try to embed the Python Interpreter into C.
In order to test this I create a shared library and 
try to load this one in Python with ctypes. Unfortunately this doesn't 
work and I would like to understand why.

Here is an example c - code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <Python.h>


int run_py(void);
int run_py2(void);

int
run_py(void)
{
    printf("hello from run_py\n");
    return 42;
}

int
run_py2(void)
{
    printf("entering c-function: run_py()\n");
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print('hello world')");
    return 0;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

So I compile this into "mylib.so" with gcc and use python3.7-config --cflags and --ldflags for linking and so on which works.

Here is the Python code I use to load this..

```
import ctypes as c
import os
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("running shared-lib integration test with python:\n{}".format(sys.version))

    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    dllfile = os.path.join(path, 'mylib.so')
    dll = c.CDLL(str(dllfile))

    print("loaded CDLL")
    dll.run_py.restype  = c.c_int
    dll.run_py2.restype  = c.c_int

    print("now calling dll.run_py()...")
    rv = dll.run_py()
    print("called dll.run_py: rv={}".format(rv))

    print("now calling dll.run_py2()...")
    rv2 = dll.run_py2()
    print("called dll.run_py2: rv={}".format(rv2))
```

So this simply loads both functions run_py and run_py2
and executes them. This is the output...

```
running shared-lib integration test with python:
3.7.1 (default, Oct 22 2018, 10:41:28) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20180831]
loaded CDLL
now calling dll.run_py()...
hello from run_py
called dll.run_py: rv=42
now calling dll.run_py2()...
entering c-function: run_py()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So basically this leads to segfault  when calling run_py2.
The cause for this is the call of `PyRun_SimpleString` .
However if I compile this as a standalone C programm 
everything seems to work just fine. I really 
would like to understand why this happens... but currently im
out ouf ideas so any feedback is really appreciated here.

BR jrsm

Comment: It looks like you are mixing two different things, embedding Python and extending Python. If your library extends Python (i.e. is loadable from within Python) you should not try to embed a Python interpreter in it (unless you want two independent unrelated Python interpreters, which I doubt).

Comment: Yes you are right, in the end I will not use  two python interpeters... only the shared library from within C (So Python embedded in C).  However I tried this as a first test (out of curiosity) and now I want to understand why it is broken ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your code a bit. Also, I'm testing on *Win* (as it's more convenient for me at this point), but I'm sure things are the same in *Nix*.

*dll00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

#define PRINT_MSG_0() printf("From C - [%s] (%d) - [%s]\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL_EXPORT_API
#endif

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL_EXPORT_API int test0();
DLL_EXPORT_API int test1();

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif


int test0()
{
    PRINT_MSG_0();
    return 42;
}


int test1()
{
    PRINT_MSG_0();
    Py_Initialize();
    PRINT_MSG_0();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(\"Hello world!!!\")");
    PRINT_MSG_0();
    return 0;
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


def main():
    dll = cts.PyDLL(DLL_NAME)
    test0 = dll.test0
    test0.argtypes = None
    test0.restype = cts.c_int
    test1 = dll.test1
    test1.argtypes = None
    test1.restype = cts.c_int

    print("Calling {:}...".format(test0.__name__))
    res = test0()
    print("{:} returned {:d}".format(test0.__name__, res))
    print("Calling {:}...".format(test1.__name__))
    res = test1()
    print("{:} returned {:d}".format(test1.__name__, res))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053609932> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x64
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL /MD /Ic:\Install\x64\Python\Python\3.5\include dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.so /LIBPATH:c:\Install\x64\Python\Python\3.5\libs
> dll00.c
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
> dll00.exp
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
> dll00.so
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Calling test0...
> From C - [dll00.c] (26) - [test0]
> test0 returned 42
> Calling test1...
> From C - [dll00.c] (32) - [test1]
> From C - [dll00.c] (34) - [test1]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "code00.py", line 30, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "code00.py", line 24, in main
>     res = test1_func()
> OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000010
> ```

The problem reproduces. First, I thought it's the [[Python.Docs]: Initialization, Finalization, and Threads - void Py_Initialize()](https://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Initialize) call. But then I remembered [[Python.Docs]: class ctypes.PyDLL(name, mode=DEFAULT_MODE, handle=None)](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.PyDLL) which states (**emphasis** is mine):

> Instances of this class behave like [CDLL](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CDLL) instances, except that the Python GIL is *not* released during the function call, and after the function execution the Python error flag is checked. If the error flag is set, a Python exception is raised.
>
> Thus, this is only useful to **call Python C api functions** directly.

Replacing *CDLL* by *PyDLL* in *code00.py*, yields:

> ```
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Calling test0...
> From C - [dll00.c] (26) - [test0]
> test0 returned 42
> Calling test1...
> From C - [dll00.c] (32) - [test1]
> From C - [dll00.c] (34) - [test1]
> Hello world!!!
> From C - [dll00.c] (36) - [test1]
> test1 returned 0
> ```

**Output** (*Nix* with *PyDLL*):

> ```
> (py_pc064_03.08_test0_lancer) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q053609932]> . ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o dll00.so dll00.c -I/usr/include/python3.8
> [064bit prompt]> python ./code00.py 
> Python 3.8.18 (default, Aug 25 2023, 13:20:30) [GCC 11.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> Calling test0...
> From C - [dll00.c] (27) - [test0]
> test0 returned 42
> Calling test1...
> From C - [dll00.c] (34) - [test1]
> From C - [dll00.c] (36) - [test1]
> Hello world!!!
> From C - [dll00.c] (38) - [test1]
> test1 returned 0
>
> Done.
> ```

Might be related:

- [[SO]: How to fix "Access Violation" error when returning PyObject from C function using PyTCC library (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55601324/4788546)
- [[SO]: C DLL crack when called from Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60083320/4788546)
- [[SO]: Python in C DLL (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72235773/4788546)
- [[SO]: Cpython Extension forcing Memory Leak (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75857942/4788546)
- [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546)

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience to test this. I replaced CDLL and it seems to work so this is nice, thank you !  Do you have an  idea why this segfault occurs ? what do you mean by only useful for python c api function calls ?

Comment: I personally, don't mean anything, it's a paste from the official doc. You know that *Python* code runs under *GIL*, meaning that every function (including *PyRun\_SimpleString*) should run so. *CDLL* "stops" *GIL*, so I guess it's *Undefined Behavior*. For more details you'll probably have to browse the *Python* source code.

Comment: Yeah  I think  it is probably hard to tell what is happening.  However I would think that there are 2 GILs, one for the embedded python and one for the other. I mean when using the multiprocessing module, hence, spawning multiple python processes, there should be also more than 1 GIL..

Comment: No there is one *GIL* (which can be active/inactive) per process. Our case is in that condition. But the problem is that a function (*PyRun\_SimpleString*) that is supposed to operate under *GIL*, doesn't because it was released by *CDLL*. Maybe it references some pointers that were invalidated by the *GIL* release.

Comment: This would mean that 2 python interpeters share the GIL ?

Comment: There is only one interpreter. Check *Py\_Initialize* doc.

Comment: What I mean is that when I execute `python code.py` the first Interpreter is started. When the library is loaded via ctypes  a second independent python interpreter should be started.

Comment: I knew what you meant, that's why I suggested to check *Py_Initialize* doc. I'm also pasting the *URL*: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Initialize.

Comment: I'm sorry I read the docs but I'm not sure what you mean. However I printed the Python version and when running with 2.7 / 3.7 its the same version printed. However i think it should be possible to embed python3 in python2? Why does it have to be the same interpreter.

Comment: I thought it was clear enough: "*This is a **no-op** when called for a **second time** (without calling Py\_FinalizeEx() first)*"