# Python in C DLL

Tags: python, c, dll

I just created a DLL in C with Python in it.
When I export my function with python functions in it, I can't call it in my Python code
But when I export a classic C function without Python code inside, it works perfectly. I don't understand

C DLL

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

__declspec(dllexport) PyObject* getList()
{
    PyObject *PList = PyList_New(0);
    PyList_Append(PList, Py_BuildValue("i", 1));

    return PList;
}
```

Python Code

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("EasyProtect.dll")

getList = lib.getList
getList.argtypes = None
getList.restype = ctypes.py_object

print(getList())
```

My Error

```
print(getList())
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000010
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [[Python.Docs]: class ctypes.PyDLL(name, mode=DEFAULT_MODE, handle=None)](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.PyDLL) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Instances of this class behave like [CDLL](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CDLL) instances, except that the Python GIL is *not* released during the function call, and after the function execution the Python error flag is checked. If the error flag is set, a Python exception is raised.
>
> Thus, this is only useful to **call Python C api functions directly**.

So, you should replace *cdll* (*CDLL*) by *pydll* (*PyDLL*). 
I enhanced your example a bit.

*dll00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif


#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API PyObject* createList(unsigned int size, int *pValues);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif


PyObject* createList(unsigned int size, int *pValues)
{
    PyObject *pList = PyList_New(size);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        PyList_SetItem(pList, i, Py_BuildValue("i", pValues[i]));
    }
    return pList;
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as ct
import sys


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")
IntPtr = ct.POINTER(ct.c_int)


def main(*argv):
    
    dll00 = ct.PyDLL(DLL_NAME)
    create_list = dll00.createList
    create_list.argtypes = (ct.c_uint, IntPtr)
    create_list.restype = ct.py_object

    dim = 5
    int_arr = (ct.c_int * dim)(*range(dim, 0, -1))  # Intermediary step: create an array
    res = create_list(dim, ct.cast(int_arr, IntPtr))
    print("\n{:s} returned: {:}".format(create_list.__name__, res))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```py
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q072231434]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL /I"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.09\include" dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll /LIBPATH:"c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.09\libs"
> dll00.c
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
>
> createList returned: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>
> Done.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the Python C API, the GIL (global interpreter lock) must be held.  Use `PyDLL` for that.  Load your DLL with:

```
lib = ctypes.PyDLL("EasyProtect.dll")
```

As an aside, your DLL has a reference leak.  `Py_BuildValue` returns a new object, and `PyList_Append` increments the reference when adding it to the list.  `Py_DECREF` should be called on the object returned by `Py_BuildValue`.

In this case, though, create the list with the size you want and use `PyList_SET_ITEM` which steals the new object's reference to initialize the list and is optimized for initializing new list items:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

__declspec(dllexport) PyObject* getList()
{
    PyObject *PList = PyList_New(1);                # size 1 list
    PyList_SET_ITEM(PList, 0, PyLong_FromLong(1));  # assign offset 0
    return PList;
}
```